# Trouble with riffleshuffling, function won't find list

Tags: python, list, function

In need of help, I'm trying to do a perfect riffleshuffle or "Faro shuffle". Been trying myself around, I made another thread but broke against rules so hopefully my question this time is better.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
def shuffle(n):
    r=[]
    for (a, b) in zip(lista[0:int(n/2)], lista[int(n/2):n]):
        r.append(a)
        r.append(b)

def riffel(n):
    lista = []
    for a in range(0,n):
        lista.append(a)
    for i in range(1,1000):
        r.shuffle()
        if lista==r:
            print("done",i)
```

What I want my function to do is pretty much count how many riffleshuffles it takes for the carddeck (in my case n, its supposed to work for any even number n) to get back to normal again (0,1,2,3,...,51). Ive seen people work this out with classes, I would like to do it without that though...

Comment: Please fix your code to show the proper indentation. This is most easily down by copy and pasting your code into the question, highlighting it, and pressing CTRL+ k. Also, your shuffle function is probably not going to work since you are initiating a list inside of the function, and not returning it (it is not an inplace shuffle and that is not how you call functions)

Comment: I hope I fixed the indentation, I tried to put the list outside the function as well, but couldnt quite make it work, I gotta say I dont really know how I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. The list `r` in riffel is never initialized.
2. You never pass `n` to `r.shuffle()`
3. (As R Nar's comment says, the state of `r` in shuffle is lost since it's scope is local.
4. Calling `r.shuffle()` is not valid since r is not an object with type shuffle.

You can fix this code as follows:

```
def shuffle(n, lista): #<--- Now passing in lista as a parameter
    r = []
    for (a, b) in zip(lista[0:int(n/2)], lista[int(n/2):n]):
        r.append(a)
        r.append(b)
    return r

def riffel(n):
    lista = []
    for a in range(0,n):
        lista.append(a)
    r_prev = lista
    for i in range(1,1000):
        r = shuffle(n, r_prev) #<--- changed how this is called, added arguments to func call
        if r == lista:         #<--- List a doesn't change so we can keep comparing to it.
            print("done",i)
        r_prev = r #<--- Making r_prevthe newly shuffled entry to pass to shuffle in next iteration
```

Comment: thank you so much for this help! working perfect after those changes!